# Eclipse usually shut down

Tags: android, eclipse, ubuntu

I use Eclipse for Android development. Eclipse shut down when there was little usage, without any "error messages" to specify why.

Here is my Eclipse log:
http://laravel.io/bin/nXWr9/raw Sorry body is limited to 30000 characters
I'm running xubuntu. Thanks in advance

Comment: What does "little usage" mean for you, because I don't understand that

Comment: Why the close votes?

Comment: My Eclipse shut down in 60 second. Or in 1-2 seconds

Answer (score 0):

Try another (perhaps even a proprietary) graphics driver. I've had the same issue on Ubuntu 14.04 on a ThinkPad with an NVIDIA graphics chip (albeit not using ADT, but I don't think this has anything to do with it).

Using the NVIDIA X Server did the trick for me.

Comment: But my graphics driver is onboard and not NVIDIA. What can I do

Comment: Mine is onboard and manufactured by NVIDIA. Try to find out which chip you have onboard (google for exact laptop model / open desktop and have a look), and see if you can find a proprietary driver for it for xubuntu.

Comment: Yes. I searched. There isn't my graphics driver for xubuntu. Although I reinstall eclipse, it shuts down.